# ¿Como puedo obtener comas y llaves en un reporte html?

Tags: html, powershell

Quiero generar un informe HTML con la clase win32_cdromdrive, necesito que el objeto CapabilityDescriptions muestre comas y llaves. En el powershell si se muestran llaves, las comas y las palabras, pero en el reporte html solo se muestran palabras

el tipo de dato del objeto CapabilityDescriptions es string

quiero que en el reporte html se vea igual que en la consola powershell

[image: PS]

html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo generas el html?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código HTML generado? Quizás con sólo CSS se puede hacer que las llaves y las comas aparezcan

Comment: Abre el archivo con el notepad en vez del navegador, quizás que te las está ocultando.

Answer (score 3):

Usa `-join` para unir los string con comas y si quieres agregarle corchetes es bastante sencillo:

```
gwmi Win32_CDRomDrive | Select @{l='Cap';e={'{'+($_.CapabilityDescriptions -join ',')+'}'}}, Caption
```